# GWT and Ext-GWT: comparision

Tags: gwt, gxt

What's the benefits if I am using Ext-GWT? Compare to GWT, What kind of benefits EXT-GWT could bring?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your application to look like all the other Sencha applications, then go for it. Sencha comes with a set of tools and widgets that might help you make a faster start, but at the end of the day, you will need a deeper understanding anyhow, and climb that hill.

My 2 cents : **go for GWT pur et dur.**

- for maximum flexibility
- for better results

but probably a steeper start.

Answer (score 1):

From the sencha site:

> Sencha Ext GWT takes GWT to the next level, giving you high-performance widgets, feature-rich templates and layouts, advanced charting, data loaders and stores, and accessibility, and much more.

I was using the widgets in a project which is nice if you need something fancy not in GWT-only.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has used both extensively, I can attest to the amount of features added by GXT... ...but, at a price.  Its deferred layout system is efficient, but it's a steep and sometimes frustrating learning curve, especially if you want to support IE<8.

Note that I haven't used GXT 3.0, but used 2.X for a large and successful enterprise application.  If you do not write some kind of web-based unit tests (selenium recommended), you will eventually get to a point where you spend more time fixing layout bug regressions than you do creating new code.

GXT can kickstart your initial development because you can produce feature rich widget very quickly (Grid is especially nice), but when it comes time to start extending and augmenting the default widgets, you're going to hit brick walls with very little documentation.

Another big gotcha...  GXT models internally serialize using a `Map<String, Object>`, which means that any types not explicitly serialized elsewhere in your RPC will give you errors when put in a GXT model.  The workaround there is to put a private, unused field of the type you want serialized (enums were my biggest pain).  Finally, gxt models are NOT default java serializable, so if you want to store them in sessions or pass them around on the server, it's not going to go well for you.

All that said, once you get the hang of GXT, and provided you don't dig too deeply into its guts, it is a great tool.  The widget sets themselves are very nice...

Basically, if you intend to create a monolithic, feature rich, complex app where you need lots of control over how things are rendered, GXT will probably get in your way.

If you want to bang out a shiny app over the weekend, don't reinvent the wheel, and just use whatever works.